# Problem while reading a smartcard in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, pcsc

I have been using the PCSC library for years to read smartcards and have never had a problem.
I entered the same code, which I do not report because it is too long and is 100% functional, in an ASPX page. If I run the web application from Visual Studio 2019 on localhost everything is fine, if I run it on the server with Windows server 2019 essential I receive this error:
**The Smart card resource manager is not running.**
I don't understand why this difference. Thanks to those who can help me.

### P.S. I don't know Java, but only c#

**UPDATE. The SCardSvr service is started on the server, but when I use the PCSC class the service stops on its own on the server. Strange behaviour.........**

Comment: Can you access the smart card from a file explorer on the Windows Server 2019?  The card needs to be unlocked and I want to find if the drivers for the card are properly installed on the 2019.  There are lots of different encryption modes for smart cards like 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit.  You may have a card that is 16 bit and 2019 may not recognize the 16 bit.  Are you using the same version of Net Library where it is working and not working?  Are the target (Net 3.5, Net 4.0, ...( for the project the same.  I've been seeing lots of issues upgrading to Net 4.7 with encryption.

Comment: The card works correctly and is located on the client pc, not on the web server. The web application and IIS settings are both on the 4.5 framework. On my pc, if I use Visual Studio everything works fine, if I open the application on the IIS server I get the error. My pc has Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: I update my question

Comment: So you are accessing the card on the client so nothing needs to be installed on the server. You obviously are trying to access the card from the server.   Make sure you are pointing to the client and not the server.  I would check Event Viewer on both client and server to see if there are any errors at time of access.  The card requires a certificate and the certificate should also be on the client

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Based on the new information the OP wants to connect a Smart Card Reader that resides on a remote computer (the client).

To the best of my knowledge this requires either a VNC or an RDP connection from the client to the server, use of the smart card redirection mechanism, and then opening the ASPX webpage from a web browser session started during the remote desktop connection.

My answer below is not applicable in this scenario at all.

**OLD ANSWER**

I would first look at the Services list on the server computer. Ensure that both Smart Card service and the Smart Card Device Enumeration Service are running when you attempt the request.

This problem may also occur due to insufficient privileges on behalf of the user account running the application pool for your ASPX page.

When you run the web page from Visual Studio 2019 it executes using derived credentials (most likely your own user account), and this account may have more privileges than the specified application pool user account on the Windows Server 2019. This applies especially if you use [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

If the problem is caused by lack of privileges, then see this [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user) for details on how to use the `sc.exe` tool to configure the privileges.

Also note jdweng's comment: if you have not installed the necessary drivers for the smart card reader to the Windows Server 2019 computer then you will need to do so in addition to configuring the privileges. Otherwise even though the ASPX page were able to access the Smart Card Resource Manager, the card reader itself has not registered there-in and thus cannot be used.

Comment: I checked the settings and they are correct, as an account I use the maximum, Administrator, I should have all the necessary permissions, I think.